# Alamofire Contextual type for closure Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, alamofire

I have the following error after upgrading Alamofire to version 2.0.0.0 using Swift 2

[image]

Anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Request Serialisation, i.e. `responseJson` changed signatures in AlamoFire 2.0. The [Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) explains in full, but the abbreviated version is as follows.

You now need to supply a closure which takes a `request`, a `response`, and a `result`. The result is an `enum`, which can either be `.Success(Value)` or `.Failure(NSData?, ErrorType)`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
    .responseJson(options: .MutableContainers) { (request, response, result) -> Void in
        print(result)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try that and see how I go when I get back home from work.